# How to check if a WildFly Server has started successfully using command/script?

Tags: wildfly, jboss-eap-7

I want to write a script to manage the WildFly start and deploy, but I'm having trouble now. To check if the server has started, I found the command

`./jboss-cli.sh -c command=':read-attribute(name=server-state)' | grep running`

But when the server is starting, because the controller is not available, `./jboss-cli.sh -c` fails to connect and returns an error.

Is there a better way to check whether WildFly started completely?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a better solution. The command is

```
netstat -an | grep 9990 | grep LISTEN
```

Check the management port (9990) state before the WildFly is ready to accept management commands.

After that, use `./jboss-cli.sh -c command=':read-attribute(name=server-state)' | grep running` to check if the server has started. Change the port
if the management port config is not the default 9990.

Here is my **start & deploy** script, the idea is continually check until the server started.

Then, use the `jboss-cli` command to deploy my application. And just print the log to the screen, so don't need to use another shell to tail the log file.

```
#!bin/sh
totalRow=0
printLog(){ #output the new log in the server.log to screen
    local newTotal=$(awk 'END{print NR}' ./standalone/log/server.log) #quicker than wc -l
    local diff=$(($newTotal-$totalRow))
    tail -n $diff ./standalone/log/server.log
    totalRow=$newTotal
}

nohup bin/standalone.sh>/dev/null 2>&1 &
echo '======================================== Jboss-eap-7.1 is starting now ========================================'
while true #check if the port is ready
do  
    sleep 1
    if netstat -an | grep 9990 | grep LISTEN
        then
        printLog
        break
    fi
    printLog
done
while true  #check if the server start success
do  
    if bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect command=':read-attribute(name=server-state)' | grep running
    then
        printLog
        break
    fi
    printLog
    sleep 1
done
echo '======================================== Jboss-eap-7.1 has started!!!!!! ========================================'
bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect command='deploy /bcms/jboss-eap-7.1/war/myApp.war' &
tail -f -n0 ./standalone/log/server.log
```

Comment: Very nice solution. I like it. I will take it over.

Comment: What if you application didn't deploy?  The port would still be open.

Comment: Hi, @stdunbar. After the server start, the port should always be open, so the server could accept management commands. If the application didn't deploy after the server start successfully,  I can see the log shown on the screen, and then solve it.